# Cannot resolve column 'id' on @JoinColumn

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa

I know there is so much posts about this and i'm searching for this problem for hours. I assigned the data sources and got rid of other "`Cannot resolve column ...`" warnings but these 2 warnings just makes no sense because the `referencedColumnName` method is referencing the same column types in particular classes on the above lines:
[image]

Why i'm getting errors on the below 2 lines but not above 2 lines?

CarBrand entity:

```
package com.sbm.insurance.entities;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table(
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(
                name = "carBrand",
                columnNames = "carBrand"
        )
)
public class CarBrands {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Car Brand can't be null or empty")
    private String carBrand;

    @Min(1)
    @Max(999999)
    private float carBrandMultiplier;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "brand",
            cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private List<Car> car;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume because classes `Account` and `Proposal` have a field called `id`, but `CarBrands` and `CarTypes` don't.

Comment: No sir, they have! They are entities too.